# Android studio 1 button 2 event

Tags: android

I have an ImageView as a button. I want it to if I click it, play a sound and switch to an another activity. In alone it works perfectly, but I cant mix them, it can only play sound, or switch activity.
Activity switch code:

```
    public void imagebutton (View v) {
    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(startNewActivity);
}
```

And the sound code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clicksound);

    ImageView click = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                             {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick (View v){
                                     sound.start();
                                 }
                             }
    );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
      @Override
       public void onClick (View v){
             sound.start();
             Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
             startActivity(startNewActivity);
        }
     }
);
```

also check .NewActivity in your manifest.xml

Comment: Thanks! "new Intent(this, NewActivity.class)" is not work, but with "new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);" it works perfectly.

Comment: you can also use context instead of MainActivity.this

Answer (score 0):

Put your code to launch the activity under `sound.start();`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clicksound);

    ImageView click = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            sound.start();
            Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(startNewActivity);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! "new Intent(this, NewActivity.class)" is not work, but with "new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);" it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a AsyncTask to reproduce your sound before start your new Activity.

```
public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clicksound); 
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping if you want
        player.setVolume(100,100); // Set Volume if you want
        player.start(); 
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use like this: BackgroundSound.execute(); before start new activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setOnCompletionListener to make sure sound is over and then start the new activity:

```
final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clicksound);
        sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(startNewActivity);
            }
        });
        ImageView click = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                sound.start();
            }
        }
```